Badge text rendering in default link navy blue
This is on Board & Card Games which still has the default site setup. Rather than showing the most recent badge Necromancer with a dark background and white text, the default coloring for links makes the text all but unreadable.

This appears to affect visited links. Middle clicking on the badge to open the details in a new tab rather than left clicking to bring up the tool tip is causing the bug to be recreated (just recreated here in meta)

